# Docker OpenJDK-8 JavaFx

Tags: java, docker, javafx

I am trying to run a java application as JAR within a Dockercontainer using the openjdk.
Now I got stuck missing the javafx dependencies.

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`/:/mnt -v `pwd`/logs:/logs --rm --network="host" openjdk:8-jdk java -jar /mnt/MyJar.jar /mnt/application-localdocker.properties
```

The used openjdk 8 version is this:
8/jdk/Dockerfile from https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/
(https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/7a33416016b60c045cf0ba99e82617ed6c130595/8/jdk/Dockerfile)

I was reading why it is excluded and different more complex ways to use it.
But that does not really help me since I do not want to build my own docker image.
I think there must be an easier way to do it. All the docs I have read so far exclude the one or other aspect but never combine them.

I would appreciate any help here...

(For the people asking why using openjdk instead of jre; I do have a database hibernate issue and I want all environments to most likely be the same. Since locally it does not occur but occurs in a dockerized Java-8-JRE environment: Spring @Schedule @Transactional on database access issue.)

Comment: So far I am using docker _airdock/oracle-jdk:jdk-8u112_ which contains javafx.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an OpenJDK 8 build which contains JavaFX you might want to have a look at [Amazon Corretto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/docker-install.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using [Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk-fx):

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN  apt-get -q update && \
     apt-get -yq install curl x11-apps && \
     curl -O https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu8.64.0.19-ca-fx-jdk8.0.345-linux_amd64.deb && \
     dpkg -i /zulu8.64.0.19-ca-fx-jdk8.0.345-linux_amd64.deb ; \
     apt-get -yq install -f
```

This is for Java 8, but Zulu also offers other Java versions.